# Persist the value of one column in two simultaneous update

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, locking

I have a column in Table Customer_Details, say Phone_Number. There would be multiple process/queries that would update the column 'Phone_Number' simultaneously. I would like to retain the value of 'Phone_Number' column after each simultaneous update. 
The default scenario would be: the latest update on 'Phone_Number' column is retained.

---

**1. Solution 1 (New columns to be added):** Have different columns for differnt process to be updated.

Eg. New columns would be inserted in table 'Customer_Details' called as 'Phone_Number_Web' and 'Phone_Number_Mobile' and then the two queries would update  respective columns. And while fetching values, these two columns data would be merged.

**2. Solution 2** (**Lock the table: Not an option**): Lock the table till one query updates and commits and then before second update take value from column 'Phone_Number' and merge it with second update and then commit.

As table lock is not an option so apart from 'Inersting new columns (Solution 1)' is there any other solution???

---

*P.S: Going further the number of queries/updates might increase on the table.*

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want the old value for the column being updated? Or do you want to retain the new value? And where do you want to retain the value? Please post an example.

Comment: Suppose Query1 updates the column 'Phone_Number' with '12345' and Query2 updates it with '6789'. But my desired result would be after Query2 update : '12345;6789'

Comment: What after multiple updates? If 10 other transactions updates it as `123`, `234`, `345` then?

Comment: Then also it should append each values as: 123;234;345;.... and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments, what you state is that you want to append the **new values** to the **existing values** whenever a row is updated.

so, what you could do is, use the **concatenation operator** in the **SET clause** of the **UPDATE** statement such that you always append the new values to the existing values.

For example,

```
SQL> create table t(a  varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t(a) values('1234');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t;

A
--------------------------------------
1234

SQL> update t set a = a||';'||2345;

1 row updated.

SQL> update t set a = a||';'||3456;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from t;

A
--------------------------------------
1234;2345;3456

SQL>
```